# How to format an html page to display the output exactly like this ..No prior experience with html

Tags: html

How to format an html page to display the output exactly like this ..

```
   Filesystem    TotalSize      SizeUtilized     SizeAvailable            Utili%
     /             48G             36G              9.9G                     79%
 /boot            487M             19M              443M                      5%
   /ai             44G            3.8G               38G                     10%
/archive           49G            180M               46G                      1%
/backup           387G            255G              113G                     70%
   /bi             44G             20G               22G                     48%
/dataC             33G             28G              3.4G                     90%
/dataO            8.7G            4.4G              3.9G                     54%
/dataW             73G             36G               34G                     52%
 /home             49G             41G              5.2G                     89%
/qadapp            49G             36G               11G                     78%
  /tmp             49G            342M               46G                      1%
/workarea          49G             38G              8.1G                     83%
/data1            185G             52G              125G                     30%
/dataM1           293G            240G               39G                     87%
/citipay           39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
  /mnt            110M               0              110M                      0%
/citiin            39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
/citipay           39G             32G              6.8G                     83%
 /cola             51G             25G               26G                     50%
```

Comment: How are creating the data for the output?

Comment: _“No prior experience with html”_ – well then see to it that you go get some. SO is not the place to teach the very basics of any technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm guessing your problem is that HTML strips spaces. To avoid that, use the **PRE** tag. Example:

```
<pre> The    spaces and new lines will not be ignored here</pre>
```

Comment: I'm rather guessing the OP didn't even try outputting as html yet.